# Oracle sql query to select columns only with matching expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys i have table which contains the following data

```
F$2051032568
F$2051032568
22342342343
3242432432432
5745745
45734554
```

When i write a oracle sql select query , i want to get only the data which does not start with or contain **F$**

```
22342342343
3242432432432
5745745
45734554
```

kindly let me know , how to do this.

Actually it is quite tricky, **without using $ in the where condition in sql query**, i need to get the data only those that doesnt match `F$`

Comment: is it possible using regular expression.

Comment: are there only numbers after F?

Comment: There can be anything after F

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use the character '$' in the WHERE clause?  If you would want to return a value F*1234 but not a value F$1234, it seems very odd that you wouldn't use a $ in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Justing: it's my guess that the OP uses a script language (Perl comes to mind...) to create the select statement, and in Perl the `$` would expand to something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
select col1 from tabl1 where col1 not like '%F$%';
```

I'm not sure, if I understand your edit:

```
select col1 from tabl1 where col1 not like ('%F' || chr(36) || '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a script language such as Perl where `$%` is expanded to something (which could be ''), you need to escape the $.

For example, again in Perl, the following wouldn't work:

```
$select_statment = "select ... from ...where the Column not like '%F$%'";
```

But this would:

```
$select_statment = "select ... from ...where the Column not like '%F\$%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1 
from tabl1  
where instr(col1,'F$')=0
```

If it is only numbers except for the F$, then you can just do:

```
select col1 
from tabl1  
where instr(col1,'F')=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the number part...
You can create a function which will evaluate the row value using the `TO_NUMBER` function.
if its invalid text then oracle will throw `ORA-01722: invalid number` exception 
Handle it in the function and then you can use the function in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp_like allows you to directly include regular expression in your where query.

Assuming, you just want records consisting of numbers only use

```
select col1 from tab1
  where regexp_like(col1, '^[[:digit:]]*$');
```

If you want to match F + something that is not a number, you could use

```
select col1 from tab1
  where not regexp_like(col1, 'F[^[:digit:]]');
```